# bridges, VLANs and RSTP

Tags: bridge, vlan

I tried to figure out how to setup RSTP on Linux with VLANs and bridges involved and now am completely confused.

I am trying to bridge three interfaces, two of which are supposed to act as trunk (hdlc0 and hdlc1) and one is supposed to act as access port (eth0). I also need to enable RSTP on each interface included in bridge, but with the configuration listed below RSTP packets are sent via hdlc0 and hdlc1 tagged (!) so other devices reject them. As Linux has no concept of 'native vlan', I have no idea how to fix it.

Here's my configuration:

```
ifconfig eth0 up


ifconfig hdlc0 up
ifconfig hdlc1 up

vconfig add hdlc0 42
vconfig add hdlc1 42
ifconfig hdlc0.42 up
ifconfig hdlc1.42 up


brctl addbr br1
brctl addif br1 eth0
brctl addif br1 hdlc0.42
brctl addif br1 hdlc1.42

ifconfig br1 up
brctl stp br1 on
```

Another question: I also wonder how to configure RSTP in scenarios where I have multiple bridges: say eth0 is trunk with vlan 42-42 allowed, vlan 42 is supposed to pass via hdlc0 and vlan 43 is supposed to go via hdlc1, so I have two bridges. If i enable RSTP on both bridges it will (probably) run independently on each bridge so I'll face problems soon?

Comment: This is a dupe of https://serverfault.com/questions/824621/linux-bridges-vlans-and-rstp (which has an answer on it).